# Export LAS from a LASD in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, lidar

How can I export a `LAS` file from an LiDAR dataset `.lasd` in ArcGIS Pro 3? I did try `Convert LAS` but it doesn't let me export/convert a `.lasd` to `.las`.

This lidar dataset was created from the `Extract LAS` tool and so the tool only brings the .lasd to the contents pane. So, I don't know where ArcGIS Pro stores las files in that dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LAS dataset file**
When a LAS dataset is created in ArcGIS Pro, a .lasd file is created and stored on disk. This .lasd file is a pointer to .las files and surface constraints used to construct the LAS dataset. The .lasd file does not import lidar point data from .lasfiles into the .lasd file. It only stores references to .las files and surface constraints.

Locate your lasd file in catalog, right-click on the lasd file, go to properties, select LAS files tab, there you will see the name of the las file you are looking for. You must have passed by it anyway while looking for your lasd file in catalog.